# validate dynamic form before submitting angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I'm dynamically creating forms with ng-repeat and they have some validation attributes (simplified version):

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="defect in model.defects">
    <form name="form_{{defect.id}}" novalidate>
      <input ng-model="defect.name" required/>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="saveDefect(defect)"/>
     </form>
</div>
```

Basically what I want to do is this:

```
$scope.saveDefect = function (defect) {
         if ($scope.<how to get the form name here>.$invalid) {
             return;
         }
}
```

Since the form name has been created dynamically with an id how do I access it? Other ways of doing the same are also welcome ofcourse :)

Comment: didn't you bind the form name to any variable???

Comment: @MohammadJavadSeyyedi what do you mean?

Comment: @Elger I added a code snipper to my answer to better explain my solution, please tell me if it's what you wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access it :

```
$scope["form_"+defect.id]
```

What I advise you to do is :

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.forms = {};
  $scope.list = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}];
  
  $scope.save = function(item) {
    if ($scope.forms["form_" + item.id].$invalid) {
      alert("error on form_" + item.id);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in list">
    <form name="forms.form_{{item.id}}" novalidate>
      <input ng-model="item.name" required/>
      <input type="submit" ng-click="save(item)" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Putting the forms in an object makes it work. Now you show me it makes me realize the repeater creates new scopes, so otherwise it won't work. Thank you!